# Visual Studio: How to get name before - of a file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

How do I get the part before the - in the filename and put the outcome in a variable?
For example a filename: test.adress-12.txt
But I only want test.adresss

I have tried searching but couldn't find anything, only things how I can find and replace something within Visual Code itself.

Comment: Don't want to be rude, but this is very trivial case of string manipulation. If you find this hard, consider taking a course (online or not or whatever form) to learn the language

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer is very trivial. It show either a lack of understanding the language or a lack of minimal research to find the answer

Comment: Seems like you also didn't read my question as well that I have searched but didn't find my answer. I would never open a question without searching first. Only this time I couldn't find and that's probably because of using wrong search terms at the time the term "split" didn't came to me. To to be fair I think you are rude! How hard is it to give someone with a question a push in the right direction. My normal language isn't VB but unix related and this time I needed to change something in an existing vb project.

Comment: Since I needed it in more places then I thought I put it in a function.
```Shared Function nodash(ByVal value As String) As String  Return value.Replace("-", "")  End Function```
And yes I never can get the formatting right here whatever I try for parts of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always know there will be a single `-` and you are using C#, then you can use [`string.Split('-')`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-7.0#definition) and take the 0th element.

C#

```
string fileName = "test.adress-12.txt";
string[] results = fileName.Split('-');
string result = results[0];
```

Here is the VB documentation for [`Strings.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.split?view=net-7.0) and here is an example of the same code in the C# example converted to VB.

VB

```
Dim fileName As String = "test.adress-12.txt"
Dim results As String() = fileName.Split("-"c)
Dim result As String = results(0)
```

Comment: I'm only using VB and not C#

Comment: Converted it with a code Converter:
`Dim fileName As String = "test.adress-12.txt"
Dim results As String() = fileName.Split("-"c)
Dim result As String = results(0)`